# java exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Tags: java, awt, awt-eventqueue

I have recently installed JDK 1.6 update 43 on my machine .Since then, whenever I try to run the event handling programs, I  encounter a problem, which says ***Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"***

Which thread does it points to?

Comment: The full stacktrace ?

Comment: i hope This link will give you the solution[check this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307283/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0

Answer (score 2):

That's the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Code involving AWT or Swing should be run on that thread. This is the thread you'll be on when in you `main` (running in the "main" thread) you typically call `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your stacktrace. At some point you will find some entry which is from your own code. Maybe a null pointer exception or similar. This is where you must look at.